# I can't get all the matches into separate arrays, and i keep getting an offset, how can I fix this?

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

```
$file = fopen("procinfo.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$proc =array();
$param=array();

while (!feof($file))

{
    $arr = fgets($file);
    $all=explode(",", "$arr");

    preg_match('/^#./', $all[0], $matches);// matches lines in an array that has a #
    $proc[] = $matches[0];

    preg_match('/^P./', $all[0], $matches);// matches lines in an array that has a P at the beggining
    $param [] = $matches[0];

}

fclose($file);
```

I want to be able to get all the matches  into separate arrays to retrieve them easier

Comment: So, what is happening that is wrong?  What do you intend to happen that isn't happening?

Answer (score 1):

If your code is giving you a warning "PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in ..." it is because there are times where $matches is `array()` (empty array) and the index 0 does not exist.

I believe the only thing you might need to do is change

```
$proc[] = $matches[0];
```

to

```
if (count($matches)) $proc[] = $matches[0];
```

and similarly change

```
$param[] = $matches[0];
```

to

```
if (count($matches)) $param[] = $matches[0];
```

Not only will these changes get rid of you offset warnings, but they will also prevent populating `$proc` and `$param` with empty elements when the line is not a match.